# SQL find different data from 1 field in 1 table and join 2 tables

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have 2 tables (people, data). In the data table I need to search 1 field for different results.

1. The primary group (is from the data table (we will call this group a)) will be people that have a code of C10* found from the code field.
2. Then I need to see how many of those (that have C10*) also have 9Nu0 OR 9Nu1
3. This data is also located in the code field within the same data table (so we will call this group b), but on a different row. If they have both 9Nu0 OR 9Nu1 only return the latest    one. Some may also have null.
4. The link between the people and data table is the entity_id=master_id
5. Finally show the dob from the people table to produce the final table or results, showing master_id, p.dob, a.eventdate, a.read_code, b.eventdate, b.read_code (as shown below).

Note: I am using Excel VBA but writing this code in SQL as I'm extracting the data from PostGreSQL database using OLEDB

Here is the people table layout:

```
entity_id   |   dob
1           |   23/09/1951
3           |   08/11/1950
30          |   17/08/1959
61          |   03/06/1957
69          |   08/03/1941
72          |   03/03/1973
105         |   28/11/1925
108         |   08/10/1934
153         |   06/08/1939
168         |   11/03/1953
```

Here is the data table layout

```
master_id   |   eventdate   |   code
1           |   11/11/2011  |   9Nu1.00
1           |   09/03/2016  |   C10E700
3           |   16/11/1999  |   9Nu0.00
3           |   01/01/2008  |   C10..00
30          |   27/11/2009  |   C10F.00
61          |   18/02/2008  |   9Nu0.00
61          |   19/12/1997  |   C10..00
69          |   01/05/1996  |   9Nu1.00
69          |   21/10/2004  |   C10F.00
69          |   01/05/1995  |   9Nu0.00
72          |   09/03/2016  |   9Nu0.00
72          |   11/11/2011  |   C10F.00
105         |   16/11/1999  |   C10..00
108         |   18/10/2005  |   C10F.00
153         |   19/12/1997  |   9Nu1.00
153         |   18/02/2008  |   C10F.00
168         |   21/10/2004  |   9Nu0.00
168         |   01/05/1995  |   C10F.00
```

and I need the result to look like this:

```
master_id   |   dob         |   a.eventdate |   a.code  |   b.eventdate |   b.code
1           |   23/09/1951  |   09/03/2016  |   C10E700 |   11/11/2011  |   9Nu1.00
3           |   08/11/1950  |   01/01/2008  |   C10..00 |   16/11/1999  |   9Nu0.00
30          |   17/08/1959  |   27/11/2009  |   C10F.00 |   18/10/2005  |   
61          |   03/06/1957  |   19/12/1997  |   C10..00 |   18/02/2008  |   9Nu0.00
69          |   08/03/1941  |   21/10/2004  |   C10F.00 |   01/05/1995  |   9Nu1.00
72          |   03/03/1973  |   11/11/2011  |   C10F.00 |   09/03/2016  |   9Nu0.00
105         |   28/11/1925  |   16/11/1999  |   C10..00 |   01/01/2008  |   
108         |   08/10/1934  |   18/10/2005  |   C10F.00 |   27/11/2009  |   
153         |   06/08/1939  |   18/02/2008  |   C10F.00 |   19/12/1997  |   9Nu1.00
168         |   11/03/1953  |   01/05/1995  |   C10F.00 |   21/10/2004  |   9Nu0.00
```

Here is my failing code

```
Sub GetData()

Const sqlconnection = "Provider=oledb;"

Dim conn As New Connection
conn.ConnectionString = sqlconnection
conn.Open
Dim rs As Recordset

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select

Dim Q7 As String
Q7 = "SELECT a.master_id, p.dob, a.eventdate, a.code, b.eventdate, b.code " _
    & "FROM data a WHERE a.code LIKE 'C10%' " _
    & "JOIN people p ON p.entity_id=a.master_id " _
    & "FROM data b WHERE ( b.code LIKE '9Nu0%' OR b.code LIKE '9Nu1%' ) " _
    & "JOIN people p ON p.entity_id=b.master_id " _
    & "ORDER BY a.master_id, a.eventdate DESC "

Set rs = conn.Execute(Q7)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Refresh
End With

rs.Close
```

End Sub

Comment: Please explicitly provide the error that you are experiencing. From a quick glance your sqlconnection parameters seems incomplete. Doesn't seem to point to the specific network resource of your PostGreSQL db.

Comment: The sql connection works fine for all the other coding. The error on this particular section is an unexpected symbol join. As i don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Not sure where you are getting the b.evendate when b.code is NULL in your sample results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the demo here:  http://rextester.com/QVXBLO35931

```
select a.master_id, p.dob, a.eventdate, a.code, max(b.eventdate), max(b.code)
from people p
join data a 
  on p.entity_id = a.master_id
  and a.code like 'C10%'
left outer join data b
  on p.entity_id = b.master_id
  and b.code like '9Nu%'
group by a.master_id, p.dob, a.eventdate, a.code
```

Comment: I have just found out that the data search for C10% (which is the primary group) is also held in another table called "prob". It is exactly the same structure as the data table. Is it possible to do a UNION ALL combining the data and prob table > then search on 9Nu%

Comment: Yes you can union them together; no need for a union all since you don't need duplicates from the two tables.  You can do it in a common table expression and do your do your filters there too.  Also I noticed I was taking max of code and eventdate separately in my example. This will work as long as the code for higher dates is always higher.  If, for example, masterid 69 had an eventdate of 01/05/1993 for code 19Nu1, then you'd get the eventdate from 19Nu0 but still 19Nu1 as the code.  So if that is possible query has to be modified a bit to always take codes based on max eventdate.

Comment: Yes I will need the date to match the code for the latest one, I did notice the date didn't match the code when I used order by master_id, so I was going to workaround that using VB. I have also tried to union them but having no success with this. You help would be most welcome.

Comment: Check out the updates at the rextester link.  In my demo, I am building the test tables using common table expressions (CTE) already which you will not need so I added a separate CTE in a comment block to show how you can join your two tables together and leave the rest of your query exactly the same.